# How is automatic update of Windows Apps from Windows Store triggered?

Tags: windows-store-apps

We are releasing a **UWP App** in **Windows Store for Business**. Users have **automatic update enabled** in the store settings.

**What triggers the update check of the store?** I could see a reboot does this some times, but I wonder if there is a schedule/trigger/service for this. I checked the documentation but I could not find anything.

My question is not about mandatory updates programmatically enforced - just about the store update process itself.

My question is related to rollout planning as we want to understand fully at which point users will be rolled out after submission to the store (including certification & visibility) was done.

Thanks

Comment: There's is a option in the App Store under Publish section in which you can mention Date/Time that you want to do a roll out of your app after certification

Comment: @Dishant Sorry, I was not clear enough. It's not about the settings in DevCenter within the Submission. My Question is about the client devices already having the app. When will the store update it? Once a day, after a reboot? My Co-Worker already got the update of our app from yesterday after he rebooted in the morning. I however don't got it till now while working the wohle day on the device and not rebooted.